# Xpath identifier for an span element with an 'i' tag inside it

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Trying to find out xpath for the element for the html code mentioned below.

Xpath works with

```
//span[@title='Open']
```

But not with

```
//span[text()='Open']
```

Trying to find out xpath with span and text. How this could be done

```html
<span class="m-t-5">
<span class="label statusopen" title="Open" onclick="javascript:toggleHistoryTab(this,'tw_831158485664530432','2302','SOLR','-1','s360-379359269');" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;">
<i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o"/>
Open
</span>
</span>
```

In my test case, more appropriate one is to find with text "Open".

Comment: can you try any of the below xpath expression, `//span[contains(text(),'Open')]` or `//span[contains(.,'Open')]` or `//span[normalize-space(text())='Open')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//span[normalize-space()='Open'][not(.//span)]
```

will select those `span` elements whose normalized string value is `"Open"` and will exclude parent `span` elements such as the one in your example with `class="m-t-5"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `XPath` for *span element with an 'i' tag inside it* you may try:

```
//span[i]
```

If you need even more specific `XPath` for *span element with an 'i' tag inside it **that contains text "Open"***:

```
//span[i[normalize-space(text())="Open"]]
```

Comment: `//span[normalize-space(text())="Open"]` this works. Removed i